# JavaScript file precedence on Safari

Tags: javascript, safari

I'm working on an application that relies heavily on JavaScript. My application works great in Chrome. However, I'm doing some testing on Safari and I've run into some problems. From what I can tell, its like one of my JavaScript files is either not loaded, or not visible. I reference two JavaScript files in my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/app.formatters.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/app.js"></script>
```

app.formatters.js has some utility methods that help me format things like date/times, text, money values, etc. app.js is the main logic for my app. app.js references a function called "formatDate" that resides in app.formatters.js. I have set an alert("here") as the first line of that file. It functions just fine in Chrome. However, in Safari, the alert is never tripped. To confuse me even further, there are no errors written in the console.

Is there some weird javascript precedence, loading thing in Safari I'm not aware of?

Thank you!

Comment: That HTML you posted will download and execute each file in sequence.

Comment: *"I have set an alert("here") as the first line of that file."* Do you mean function?

Comment: Yes. I meant function. My apologies.